# Eclipse CDT C/C++ colorize custom keywords

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'd like to add some custom keywords to Eclipse CDT, to be at least colorized like default C/C++: if, else, switch, etc

Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Neon.1 Release (4.6.1)
Build id: 20160913-0900

I tried some examples by altering Template but didn't work

Window -> Pref -> C/C++ -> Editor -> Templates -> New...

What I like to colorize is a macro like this

```
WaitHere(TMO_WAIT_BAUD_RATE_CHANGE);
   ^
   |
   to be in color like default keywords

WaitHere (${arguments})  // not working
WaitHere ${name} // not working
```

More specific, I would like some custom colors for my keywords, but at least to be highlighted as default C/C++ will be fine.

Thank you

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: C/C++ > Editor > Syntax Coloring_ you can set the color for _Code > Macro references_, but not different colors for different macros. Maybe there's a plug-in that can do that.

Comment: I know that, but will colorize all macros in the same way...In fact I want some specific keywords, not necessarily macros, like in N++ we can add new keywords via XML file

Comment: For non-macros, you can specify a symbol to colorize it as _Macro references_ as follows: in _Project > Properties: C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols_, in the tab _Symbols_ click _Add_ and enter the name `WaitHere` and the value `/**/`.

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this besides writing a plugin that hooks into the `org.eclipse.cdt.ui.semanticHighlighting` extension point.